# Always replace " with \enquote{ or }

Tags: latex, auctex

You can configure AuCTeX to automatically replace `"` with `\enquote{` or `}`, if the package `csquotes` is loaded, which is great.

But when I am using my own custom class, where `csquotes` is loaded in the class file, Emacs does not recognize it and therefore instead replaces `"` with ``` `` ```.

How can I make AuCTeX also in this case replace `"` with `\enquote{` or `}`?

Because I always use the package `csquotes`, it does not have to recognize, whether the package is loaded in some class or package file, but instead it can always assume that it is loaded. (Actually, I would even prefer the latter, since I suspect the former to be complex and more prone to errors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX provides an interface for this: Write your own AUCTeX style file which corresponds to your own custom LaTeX class file.  Suppose the name of your custom class is `classname.cls`.  A simple skeleton for your `classname.el` can look like this:

```el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "classname" ;; Replace with the real name of your class
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "article" ;; or which .cls you load
                        "csquotes"))
 :latex)
```

Now save this `classname.el` in a directory which is listed in the variable `TeX-style-private` (or adjust is accordingly), and make sure you have this in your init file:

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

With this setup, AUCTeX should recognize that you're using `classname` inside the argument of `\documentclass` once you open your .tex file and load its support files for `article` and `csquotes` which should give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: I did not know about style files. This fixes the problem and tells me to read the AuCTeX manual again. Thank you!